# relocation truncated to fit error whilst cross-compiling qtwebkit

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to cross-compile QTWebKit for a Beaglebone. I can successfully cross-compile QtCore, but attempting to cross-compile QtWebkit results in the following errors:

```
    /home/doug/workspace/qt5.6_ARM7/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore//.obj/llint       /LowLevelInterpreter.o: In function `llint_eval_prologue':
LowLevelInterpreter.cpp:(.rodata+0x65): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_THM_CALL against symbol `llint_entry_osr' defined in .text section in /home/doug/workspace/qt5.6_ARM7/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore//.obj/llint/LLIntSlowPaths.o
```

This has happened over multiple versions of Qt. I'm using gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf cross-compiler.

I'm cross-compiling using a mounted SD card image of the target platform's debian install, if that's of any relevance.

If anyone has any insights, they'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem of your elfutils. Make sure that you have sane C(XX)FLAGS and if you are using LTO, re-check it's setup.